# UITapGestureRecognizer static method crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a swift app with multiple custom `UICollectionViewCell`s. All of the cells have multiple objects (either `UIImageView` or `UILabel`) that the user can tap on (hence, I use multiple `UITapGestureRecognizer`s to call the corresponding action. Now, to ease my job and make the code less repetitive, I wanted to create an `extension` of `UITapGestureRecognizer` with a `static` method that I can call directly on the class.

I did, but the fact that the app crashes means that there's something I didn't do well. Here's my code:

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {
    static func addNewTapGuestureRecognizer(for imageView: UIImageView, selectorName: Selector) {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selectorName)
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    static func addNewTapGuestureRecognizer(for label: UILabel, selectorName: Selector) {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selectorName)
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}

class TextCVC: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        addTapGuesturesForImagesAndLabels()
    }

    func addTapGuesturesForImagesAndLabels() {
        UITapGestureRecognizer.addNewTapGuestureRecognizer(for: postActionShareImageVIew, selectorName: #selector(self.shareImageTapped))
        UITapGestureRecognizer.addNewTapGuestureRecognizer(for: postActionLikeImageVIew, selectorName: #selector(self.likeImageTapped))
    }

    @objc func shareImageTapped() {
        print("share")
    }

    @objc func likeImageTapped() {
    }
}
```

The console error says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UITapGestureRecognizer
>   likeImageTapped]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1b52e4c50'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be here :
`let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: selectorName)`

The target is not `self`, it's the instance of the UICollectionViewCell.

Change your code to  :

```
static func addNewTapGuestureRecognizer(for imageView: UIImageView, target: Any, selectorName: Selector) {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: target, action: selectorName)
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the target so replace this

```
 static func addNewTapGuestureRecognizer(for imageView: UIImageView, selectorName: Selector) {
```

with

```
static func addNewTapGuestureRecognizer(for imageView: UIImageView, selectorName: Selector , myTarget:UICollectionViewCell) {

     let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: myTarget, action: selectorName)


 }
```